# Best style for iterating over a small number of items in Python?

Tags: coding-style, python

I was just reading a presentation on python and I noted that the author had missed out the round brackets of the tuple for the items to iterate over, and it struck me that I might be inclined to leave them in. A quick re-read of [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) gave no definitive answer, and I didn't want to 'fall-back' on the old "explicit is better than implicit" without some discussion; so ...

Which do you prefer? Which do you think is more pythonic in these two equivalent for statements (limit the discussion to its use in for statements).

```
>>> # Some setup
>>> x, y, z = 1, 'Hi', True
>>> 
>>> #Style 1: Implicit tuple
>>> for i in x, y, z:
    print(i)


1
Hi
True
>>> # Style 2: Explicit tuple
>>> for i in (x, y, z):
    print(i)


1
Hi
True
>>>
```

Comment: What also struck me was that I had previously never thought about the alternatives?

Comment: The problem with "a small number of items" is that after the script has been modified once or twice, you find you've "a large number of items".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with **Style 2**, as you can actually understand what you are iterating over:

```
>>> # Style 2: Explicit tuple
>>> for i in (x, y, z):
        print(i)
```

Style 1 seems a bit confusing to me for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

I make a point to do neither.  I've found that code readability improves if you assign the tuple to a descriptive variable.

For instance:

```
for name in relative_names:
    print name
```

vs

```
for name in "Tyler", "Robert", "Marla", "Chloe", "Lou":
    print name
```

Comment: I note that you had to expand the original x, y, z to make your point though ;-)

Comment: Not always . What if one had lists such as skinny, slim, fat, and obese. iterating over fat + obese might be better than finding a good name for fat + obese, assigning the variable then looping over the new variable - it can make more sense to know the detail when the detail is not complex, and it is only to be used once.

Comment: I did expand the original (x,y,z) to make my point, because all too often code expands beyond a simple (x,y,z), but if you are not writing complex or reusable code, as your second comment suggests, it's not really worth debating.

Answer (score 1):

I would always prefer:

```
>>> # Some setup
... some_values = 1, 'Hi', True,
>>> 
>>> # Style 3: named tuple
... for value in some_values:
...     print(value)
... 
1
Hi
True
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case explicit is better than implicit, the tuple should be obvious.

I think there are bigger fish to fry though :) Anybody will know what you are up to in either case, and it's a tiny change.